# ERROR CODE 7- Cannot download needed file for the program

Tags: mindstorms, nxt, software

I am kind of new in LEGO MINDSTORMS, I tried to download a program to the NXT robot and got the Error code 7- "Cannot download needed file for the program" - can someone tell me what should i do?

Comment: Try uninstalling and then reinstalling the NXT programming software. That might help.

Comment: A screenshot of the program may help too.

Answer (score 2):

This is most probably an accessory file (sound or image) not present on your machine. Verify all the sound or display blocks that might use such non-standard contents.